# What event log should I check for Hardware Changes

Tags: windows-10, event-log

Approximately every 10 seconds my PC seems to be adding new hardware then instantly removing it. For example, you know the sound when you insert a new USB device and it starts to look for drivers? It is playing that sound and then the associated device removal sound instantly afterwards. It is doing this approx. every 10 seconds.

Device Manager also does a refresh but it is too quick to see any changes.

I did a [screen record](https://youtu.be/R9UA_kZf9DM) to show what I mean. The second time in the video it doesn't look like Device Manager refreshed - it did but for some reason my screen record software seemed to miss it.

I had a look in Event Viewer but couldn't see anything - probably partly because I'm not entirely sure where to be looking. `Hardware Events` under `Applications and Services Logs` is empty.

Running Windows 10 Enterprise with all available updates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the device causing the issue is a USB device (Which I'm suspicious it could be), you could use [USBLogView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html) to monitor it. This will only show events occurring whilst the program is running, although it seems like it's happening regularly enough for you to do this.

Alternatively, you can check the `Event Viewer` log in `Windows Logs` -> `System` to see if any device errors are occurring.

Comment: Using WIn10 I dont see `System` in `Windows Logs`