# Find out what is causing add/remove hardware sound

Tags: windows-10, hardware-detection

I have a Windows 10 computer that every 5 minutes or so, plays the Windows Add/Remove hardware "removal" sound and then a few seconds later plays the "added hardware" sound. Sometimes it does this four or five times in immediate succession.

No changes are being made to the computer, so I suspect I have a faulty peripheral.

Without disconnecting things and waiting to see if it goes away (it could be an on-board peripheral that is flaky, but cannot be physically unplugged) how can I figure out what is causing the add/remove hardware sounds to play? Is there an event in the event log somewhere I can look at?

---

Update: I have used `usblogview` which did show an offending peripheral. However even with that peripheral unplugged the issue is still occurring, but now `usblogview` is not showing anything, which means it's likely not a USB device causing it. Maybe it's the USB chip itself on the motherboard? I have enabled `Audit PNP Activity` as per HelpingHand's comment however I don't see any events in the event log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What event log should I check for Hardware Changes](https://superuser.com/questions/1039710/what-event-log-should-i-check-for-hardware-changes)

Comment: @Romen if it's USB related it might, but it might not be. I have a bunch of non-USB peripherals as well. I'll try it and see

Comment: Did you check the System logs in Event Viewer? (Which is also mentioned by that possible duplicate)

Comment: You can turn on such auditing to the Security Event log for PnP.  Run: `gpedit.msc`, then Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Advanced Audit Policy Configuration > System Audit Policies > Detailed Tracking.  Audit PNP Activity can then be enabled.

Comment: So I closed this as a duplicate thinking that the USB monitor had caught the offending item. However even though it's unplugged I'm still constantly getting the noise, but no USB device is showing up. So I suspect it's something deeper. I have turned on `Audit PNP Activity` however I can't see where it goes in the event log

Comment: @HelpingHand I eventually tracked down the issue using your advice. That info went into the Security event log (which was unexpected, I expected it to be in System or Hardware event log). It looks like a faulty USB hub on the motherboard. If you post your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @MarkHenderson - I have added an answer.  Sorry, I should have mentioned the event log it went to initially.

Comment: @MarkHenderson could you tell me what you saw in the Security Event log that showed you what was happening? I am having the same issue but can not figure out what to do. ALso, what did you do about this faulty USB hub to get the sound to stop?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I sent the motherboard back to the manufacturer and had them replace it. I don't have that install of Windows any more so I don't have a PNP Activity event to refer to any more, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the device in question is Plug-n-Play (PnP) then you can enable auditing.

To configure locally using the group policy editor:

1. Launch gpedit.msc
2. Navigate to:

> Computer Configuration >  Windows Settings >  Security Settings > 
>   Advanced Audit Policy Configuration >  System Audit Policies > 
>   Detailed Tracking.

Audit PnP Activity can then be enabled for success/failure.

[image: Local group policy editor]

The explanation for this option is as follows:

> PNP Activity
>
> This policy setting allows you to audit when plug and play detects an external device.
>
> If you configure this policy setting, an audit event is generated
>   whenever plug and play detects an external device. Only Success audits
>   are recorded for this category. If you do not configure this policy
>   setting, no audit event is generated when an external device is
>   detected by plug and play.
>
> Volume: Low

To view the logs, launch the Windows Event Log, e.g. eventvwr and open the Security event log.

If needed, from the command line you can check the state by running:

> AuditPol /get /category:"Detailed Tracking"

To enable auditing of failure and success for Plug and Play Events:

> AuditPol /set /subcategory:"Plug and Play Events" /failure:enable /success:enable

To disable:

> AuditPol /set /subcategory:"Plug and Play Events" /failure:disable /success:disable