# Windows 10 - endless device disconnect sound notification

Tags: windows-10, audio, notifications

I recently reinstalled my operating system Windows 10 .. I installed a few apps, updates etc. then suddenly my computer is sending me endless device disconnect sound notifications.

Thinking maybe it was something wrong with a USB connection I removed all connections and still heard the sound playing. I then downloaded a small utility called [USBLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html) to see if there actually USB events triggering the sound which it turns out there were not.

So I opened Task Manager and just started killing processes to see if I could narrow it down. It turns out killing Explorer stopped the sound, but I am still not sure what event is triggering the sound itself.

I read another [Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1039710/what-event-log-should-i-check-for-hardware-changes) which suggested to check the `Event Viewer log` in `Windows Logs` -> `System` to see if any device errors are occurring however there is no such `System` directory in my Logs folder. I decided to look in the Event Viewer to see if there was anything there (I am in experienced and dont know what I'm looking for mind you), but found :

[image]

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Launch permission for the COM Server application with CLSID Windows.SecurityCenter.WscDataProtection and APPID
```

**I am not sure if this might be causing the sound?
EDIT I did a system restore to a point before this issue started and the sound is still playing**

One thing to note is that the sounds occurs before I am logged in (at the startup page where we are asked for our PIN).

An easy workaround is to simply disengage the sound in sound properties, but I really dont want to ignore what is causing this, and I would also like to have that sound happen when it is supposed to.

I have also tried the solution proposed in [THIS](https://superuser.com/a/1510786/598567) answer to another user who was having the same issue, but the problem persists.